# How do I change my review decision?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Suppose that I made a wrong decision about a suggested edit. Let's say I wrongly choose 'Approve'.

Is there a way I can retract my decision or change it?

Comment: You can go back and edit the question or answer after it has been approved or rejected.

Comment: Slow down, don't rush, and don't make the mistake in the first place.

Comment: This is why multiple people look at edits.

Comment: Related feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186590/the-ability-to-undo-reviews

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way to change or revoke your decision.

Answer (score 3):

@Servy is right, you cannot change your *review*. But, there's still a way to force the suggested edit itself to be rejected. It used to be quite simple (see below), but as @DonaldDuck mentioned in the comments, that doesn't work anymore. The procedure will reject the pending edit as conflicting with yours. Of course, this should only be done if there's actually anything to improve in the post.

You need a Stack Apps key and access token with write access. You can [register one yourself](https://stackapps.com/q/8971/34061) and obtain a key, and then an [access token](https://stackapps.com/q/9345/34061). You can use those to [edit an answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-answer) or a [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question) - most of the fields are self-explanatory, but `preview` needs to be set to `false` to do an actual edit. `comment` is the edit summary.

This is all so convoluted (even for me, as a Stack Apps moderator) that I'd rather [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/295232) the post and undo/improve any changes when the edit is actually approved ...

<sub>The simple option was that you used to be able to navigate to the edit page of the post (`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<post id>/edit`) and improve the post yourself. That doesn't work anymore ...</sub>

Comment: Note that this causes the suggested edit to not count toward editing bans...so it's not desirable in some cases.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Trying to do this just redirects to the suggested edit in the review queue.