# The ability to undo reviews

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review

I (and probably many other people) have accidentally clicked the wrong button in reviews. For example, I just clicked the <kbd>**Leave Open**</kbd> button when I wanted to click <kbd>**Close**</kbd>. I think many people have done this. I think an ability to undo this would be appreciated.

Comment: What about not making a mistake in the first place? If you want to, I can write a user script for you which delays the click handler for 5 seconds after clicking.

Comment: @RobW Humans are humans: they WILL make mistakes. And sure, that could work **if** you can cancel it.

Comment: Then you're going to cancel the delay, and we're back at the initial problem, right?

Comment: @RobW waiting 5 sec after each click will really slow down the review process, which causes less reviews per day...

Comment: @WouterJ There's a limit on purpose.

Comment: @RobW What I mean is that it's useless if you can't cancel the click event.

Comment: @WouterJ It was an arbitrary low number grabbed from the thin air. If it's smaller, say 2, then one doesn't have enough time to undo the choice.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Ah, so you're fine with being forced to wait for 5 seconds? During this period, you'll get the opportunity to cancel your choice.

Comment: @RobW I'd be fine with it if I could cancel the click.

Comment: @RobW and that's why delaying an action to not make an error is a bad idea imo. Humans make errors, slowing down each review just for that 1/1000 change of making an error is not a good idea...

Comment: @WouterJ I would disagree with 1/1000. I've done about ~700 reviews, and I've easily made two or three errors.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance Two or three errors on 700 is not much (though personally I have never made a mistake, I only review "Suggested edits" though, and sometimes a close vote - with full attention).

Comment: @RobW I pay attention, it's more of a misclick (my mouse DPI is 5.7K)

Comment: I knew this would happen: even though downvotes are different, please tell me why you don't like my proposal? Because it would slow down your review spamming?

Comment: @Shog9 Why declined? I kind of suspected that it would be, but could we have an official explanation?

Comment: @Undo He's probably typing it up now.

Comment: See my answer, @Undo. This is a huge amount of added complexity.

Comment: It's probably also worth noting that you can still go back and vote to close a question after hitting "leave open" (same for delete, flag, etc). While this won't be reflected in your review, it's a good option if you really screwed up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Destructive actions (close, delete, flag) already have a confirmation that you'll need to click through before proceeding. Editing requires you to actually make changes before submitting. This leaves various "it's ok" responses. While it's certainly *unfortunate* if you click these when there's an actual problem with the post, it's not exactly critical that you be able to change this response either; if there's a problem, someone else will catch it eventually.

Note that "undo" is tricky in all cases, even the relatively benign "do nothing" ones: if the review has completed, and particularly if significant time has passed *since* it completed, changing your response may not be possible.

I think the cost of this outweighs the advantages at this point.

Comment: Maybe a cooldown for undoing would be nice. I accidentally put a new question as "looks ok" in the first question review queue.

Answer (score 6):

We could have a button next to the post in the *activity->reviews* listing in the user profile.  It would need to exist depending on the queue type, and the status of the post.

- Closed Votes - If closed then no button.
- Suggested Edit - If edit has already been a approved then no button.
- First Posts - If approved then no button.
- Late Answers - If approved then no button.
- Low Quality Posts - If approved or deleted then no button.
- Reopen Votes - If reopened then no button.

*Note*, that I'm not sure of the complete workflow for the First, Late and Low queues, i.e. whether it takes multiple users to take them out of the queue or not.

If any of these have been completed so that the button doesn't exist, then they can click on the post link and maybe do something (though they would have already used their close/reopen votes in those queues).