# Revoking one's own review decision on demand

Tags: discussion, support, review

I made a review on `TeX.SX` today concerning a **Late answer** and I have to admit, that I accidentally hit the "Nothing Action needed** although I wanted to edit and comment the post, because it was a new question instead of an answer.

Is there a way to revoke this `Approving` and remove it from my review count? I do not think that the steps (if possible at all) are `TeX.SX` specific.

Comment: No, such thing is not possible. Just learn the lesson and move on, mistakes happen. :)

Comment: In case you meant this to be a feature request, it's dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186590/the-ability-to-undo-reviews

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Well, I have some experience with reviewing, but it annoys me anyway.. ;-)

Comment: You can still go back and edit the post though. And you can follow the link and add a comment. Those this won't count toward the review process, it's more to the spirit of what that review queue is there for anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot retract a review vote after the fact.

I would not worry too much about it, mistakes happen but there are other reviewers that'll pick up the post. You can still go back to the *post itself* and comment and edit there.

Comment: Well, I have to learn from it ;-)