# How to change my decision on a rejected suggested edit as the post owner?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

As the post owner, I have accidentally rejected an edit by mistake on my question:
[Selenium Cucumber JS - How to pass data from the feature file to step definition file using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421634/selenium-cucumber-js-how-to-pass-data-from-the-feature-file-to-step-definition)

Suggested edit review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20915232

The above is the URL to the question, if anybody has 2000+ rep could you please revert this? It's marked on the user's profile and I don't think that's fair considering it was just a misclick.

Comment: If you want someone to fix it, you should ask on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). Generally speaking, you don't need to worry about it, because you're not the only one reviewing edits.

Comment: @ale looks to me like they both own the post and rejected the edit, in that case, the vote is binding as far as I know...

Answer (score 5):

First, I suggest to let the rejected editor know via comment that you rejected their edit by mistake. You can let them know that, if they suggest the edit again, you will approve it.

See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/377968):

> Additionally, moderators can override the outcome to any suggested edit, in addition to the post author. They are the only ones who can override outcomes on suggested edits to tag wikis, as those have no specific owner.

Asking in chat is not always possible / successful, but you can simply flag your own post for moderator attention and explain that you rejected the edit by accident.

To the question whether reviews could be undone, Shog9's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186737/377968) was:

> Note that "undo" is tricky in all cases, even the relatively benign "do nothing" ones: if the review has completed, and particularly if significant time has passed since it completed, changing your response may not be possible.
>
> I think the cost of this outweighs the advantages at this point.

In your case, the following happened:

1. Suggested edit was approved by 2 reviewers -> creating revision 2
2. When notified of the edit, you clicked "reject" and thereby overrode it -> creating revision 3

So you actually rolled back the edit, while it just looks as if you reviewed it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i think i'll flag it, might be the quickest way to remedy the situation.

Thanks again!

Comment: *(sorry for earlier comment deletion as I wanted to verify something first)* Mods can't override a suggested edit rejection by post owner. Any user with edit privileges should be able to rollback to the revision that was rejected, however that wouldn't change the suggested edit rejection outcome.

Comment: @SamuelLiew It looks like the author there overrode an approval by reviewers, and you can't override that since it's already been overridden. But is it really true that mods can't override edits if they were *reviewed* (not overridden) by their authors?

Comment: Yup, I only see the "next" button, no "approve"

Comment: @SamuelLiew And you're sure that that's on a review that was simply *reviewed*, **not** *overridden*? For instance, are you able to override [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5656866)?

Comment: @Sonic I can reject the one you linked. Seems that the reason why mods cannot approve an author reject is due to the fact that a new revision is created, and therefore the suggested edit is no longer the last revision. Sorry, when I meant the author "overrode" the review, I meant cast the binding vote on the suggested edit (which is also linked to the review).

Comment: @SamuelLiew No, what happened here is that the edit was approved by reviewers, then the approval was overridden by the author. Keep in mind that for quite a while, SO has only required two reviews to dequeue and dismiss a suggested edit. My question was, as a mod, are you able to still override if the author *reviewed* the edit, **not** *overrode* it, which you answered as *yes*. If the author simply *reviews* an edit, it won't create a new revision on top of the suggested one.

Comment: You're right, it was already approved, creating a revision (rev.2). The author actually *reviewed* it (perhaps looking at the revisions?) and pressed the reject button, therefore creating a third (rollback) revision. This is what I see on the review https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhS35.png

Comment: @SamuelLiew The author got the notification of a suggested edit, and clicked the "Reject" button, which was the sole button there, thus overriding it. This causes them to *display* as a reviewer of the edit, but it doesn't mean that they actually *reviewed* it when it was still pending.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Wrong. Samuel Liew's first few comments were incorrect.

Comment: What *actually* happened was that the edit was approved by reviewers, then the author overrode it by mistake. As evidenced by [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315706/how-to-change-my-decision-on-a-rejected-suggested-edit-as-the-post-owner#comment1034680_315709), mods *can* override suggested edits if the post author reviewed it while it was still pending. But that's not what happened in this case.

Comment: Is it now better?

Comment: Yes, it's correct now.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it, i'm sorry i've caused a fuss! =] Thanks for being a great community.